# Зачем при отрисовке каждый раз заново рисовать одно и то же?

Tags: html5, canvas, render

Читаю одну статью по канвасу html5. Это рисовалка при помощи линий. Так вот при добавлении каждой новой линии автор очищает канвас и заново рисует все предыдущие. И в этом есть смысл, если ты хочешь сделать отмену действий или слои. Но разве не лучше будет делать отрисовку полностью заново только в случаях, когда это действительно нужно?

Я за графику никогда не брался и не знаю, насколько глуп этот вопрос и есть ли в таком способе смысл. Прошу объяснить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, из-за того, что в большинстве задач обычно фон всё-таки нужно очищать (даже если бо́льшая часть холста остаётся неизменной, это всё равно куда проще, чем выяснять, что именно изменилось).

Это, конечно, лишняя работа, но вообще если на отрисовку всего кадра уходит больше времени, чем проходит между кадрами, лучше оптимизировать в самой отрисовке (может, например, кешировать сложные группы в битмапы и выводить уже их), а не экономить на перерисовываемых областях. В какой-нибудь ситуации понадобится нарисовать сразу всё (хоть на первом кадре) и страничка подвиснет.

Comment: Но если у меня задача - банально рисовать (карандашом и ластиком), пусть и разными цветами и размерами, без возможности отменить или ещё что-либо сделать?

Comment: А, тогда да, очищать будет явно излишне.